# Forms authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, forms-authentication

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0. And I am implementing Forms authentication.

I want to know in Forms authentication, how to check whether a user is already authenticated or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check whether they're authenticated. For example

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
Response.Write("Logged in already");
}
else
{
Response.Write("Please log in");
}
```

Comment: When User.Identity will be set? In my current code, I just call "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(someusernumber, false)", will this method set User.Identity?

Comment: Yes it will because SetAuthCookie authenticates the user. You may have to reload the page after setting the cookie. A check for authentication after SetAuthCookie will return true.